# Encrypting with RSA

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to program my own RSA implementation, but I'm having some trouble.

I have the private and public keys that contain (n, e) and (n, d) respectively, but I'm not sure how to use them to encrypt. I've encoded plaintext that I wish to encrypt into a very large integer - is it just as simple as raising that number by e in the case of encryption? I doubt it because I'm not using n anywhere although I'm sure I need to.

Here's my code:

```
def encrypt(self, plaintext_file, encrypted_file):
    with open(plaintext_file, 'rb') as fin:
        plaintext_bin = fin.read()
        plaintext = plaintext_bin.decode('utf-8')

    with open("public.txt", "r") as fin:
        lines = fin.readlines()
        n, e = int(lines[0].strip()), int(lines[1].strip())

    alphabet = ".,?! \t\n\rabcdefcdghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    encoded = self.to_base10(plaintext, alphabet)
    encrypted = pow(encoded, e)  # is this right?
```

I'm also curious how I can decrypt to verify that it's working.

Comment: (n,e) public (n,d) private, what is modulus? you have to raise m^e mod n

Answer (score 1):

The [*Wikipedia* page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption) for RSA includes the exact algorithm for encryption.

```
c = m^e mod n
```

You need to add `n` to the end of your `pow` call:

```
encrypted = pow(encoded, e, n)
```

You can then decrypt by:

```
plaintext = pow(encrypted, d, n)
```